# How do I loop through browser changing the address from a list? (Python 3 / Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I know my code is not the prettiest or cleanest but I wanted to start learning python by web scraping. This is what I have so far and need help looping thourgh this list and adding each item in the list for each loop.

Each loop should look like this:

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/A/cash-flow?p=A'
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AA/cash-flow?p=AA'
```

Thanks in advance!

```
all_tickers = ['A', 'AA', 'AAAU', 'AACG', 'AADR', 'AAL'

def tics(t):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    for index in range(len(all_tickers)):
        url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + index + '/cash-flow?p=' + index
        driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `range` function, it is better to iterate and take the elements:

```
all_tickers = ['A', 'AA', 'AAAU', 'AACG', 'AADR', 'AAL']

def tics(t):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    for index in all_tickers:
        url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + index + '/cash-flow?p=' + index
        driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `range(len(all_tickers))` you are iterating over the indices and not the elements themselves. 
If you replace 
`url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + index + '/cash-flow?p=' + index` 
with 
`url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + all_tickers[index] + '/cash-flow?p=' + all_tickers[index]`
it should work. 
Or you can replace `range(len(all_tickers))` with `all_tickers` as that would iterate over the elements.